# With a WP8.0 app in the Windows Phone store. What does the user's Win 8.1 phone display if there is a Universal App with same name?

Tags: windows-phone-8

If I have a WP8.0 Phone App in the Windows Phone store, and later create a Universal App with same name, do the two phone apps show up in the store next to each other in a Win8.1 phone? Or does the user's phone only display one app - the Universal phone app for a Win 8.1 Phone or the WP8.0 for a Win 8.0 phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only display two different apps win Windows Phone 8.1 if you have submitted two different apps.

The ideia here is to have only one app, and in that app you can sumbit two versions: one that supports only Windows Phone 8.1, and the one that supports Windows Phone 8.

In that case every device (regardless of the version) will have only the version that they currently support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Same app, different versions. But Win8.1 phones support Win8.0 apps. So it supports both WP8.0 and Universal, how does it decide which to present to the user on his device when visiting the store?

Comment: The Windows Phone Store does that management. You don't have to worry about it.

Comment: So I can upload my Wp8.0-package plus a Universal App for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1?